# Empty edgeworth box

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, exchange

Can a empty edgeworth box be a pareto set? What kind of economy would be describe in this situation?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive endowments then I can think of two cases

1. we are looking at an edgeworth box before any useful information is displayed on it, so we really *don't* know what that info would be like.
2. we are dealing with some exotic model where the subset of $\mathfrak{R^2}$ defined by the endowments is not reachable; the endowments are '*too little*' in a sense, if that makes any sense.

please note that the second case could be an abnormal specification or it could well may be a perfectly acceptable one, albeit constrained to some appropriate set.

also, as far as the former case is concerned, consider the box as a zoom on a region where the economic problem is restricted from reaching.

On a general note, the edgeworth box is a tool that assists in visualizing equilibrium positions (contract curves and the such); having an empty edgeworth box-aside from very unusual circumstances-is not very helpful.